# Building boost with a different compiler on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, boost, qt-creator, qmake

I'm trying to figure out how to build the boost C++ libraries on Mac OS X **with a different compiler** than Apple's own.

I have both Xcode 4.5 (with command-line developer tools) and QT Creator installed on my computer, which means that when I issue bootstrap.sh and b2, the system will utilize the default Apple compiler.

I believe there's some configuration that I need to do with my environment variables, but I have no idea of what should I pass as toolset (since it seems that qmake is not one of the options listed).

This is how I'm using b2 right now with Apple's compiler:

```
./b2 link=static threading=multi toolset=darwin architecture=x86 target-os=darwin address-model=32_64 stage
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot build anything with qmake, because qmake is a Makefile generator, not a compiler. You have to use GCC or some other compiler to compile Boost and then add it to your qmake project file to be linked.

Comment: Ok, the question was wrong. Thanks, I edited the question to reflect what I need.